# infinite loop with jQuery .stop()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I was fooling around with jQuery's `stop()` and ended up with an infinite loop.
The idea was (just out of experimentation) to create an animation with a "step" condition which would check whether the element's css property reached a certain value and, in that case, stop the animation right in its tracks, clearing the queue AND completing the animation immediately.

I know this may sound silly as it's probably not the way `.stop()` is meant to be used, but I thought you might give me an answer for this unexpected behavior.

Here's the code:

```
$("#element").animate({
    "width": "500px",
    "height": "130px"
}, {
    "duration": 850,
    "step": function () {
        var currentWidth = $(this).width();
        if(currentWidth >= 295) $(this).stop(true, true);
    }
}).slideUp(700);
```

I found out the infinite loop is caused by the second `true` passed to `stop()` - that is, the parameter that tells the animation to be immediately completed.

It probably has something to do with the 'step' function, but can anybody please explain me this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Calling :

```
$(this).stop(true, true);
```

will execute the `step` function for the very last step.  Within that call you are calling stop again. The animation is not removed from the queue until that `step` function completes.  Since the animation is still on the queue, calling `stop` again executes the last `step`... on and on.

Comment: Thank you, I don't completely understand your answer though, but let's see if I got the main point: when I call .stop(true, true) the animation runs once more for the very last time and executes the "step"... in the "step" .stop is called again and causes the animation to run again for the very last time... and so on, and an infinite loop is created... is it correct? Also, could you provide some code which shows how to correctly achieve what I'm trying to? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably doing something like this:

1. Run animation frame
2. Run step function
3. Step condition true
4. Stop animation, but finish it immediately
5. Run last animation frame to finish animation
6. Run step function (loop back to step 2)
7. Set animation frame as complete (never reached)
8. Set animation as complete (never reached)

If you can check if the step is occurring in the last animation frame, you can take that into account when calling stop().